# How to refactor common css rules in media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm defining a couple of media queries, and I'm having some duplicated code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .list__figure {
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 80px;
  }
  .list__content {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  .ico-bim--over-img {
    left: 5px;
    right: inherit;
    top: 5px;
  }
  .ico-lnb-valid--over-img {
    left: 78px;
    top: 5px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1040px) {
  .list__figure {
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 80px;
  }
  .list__content {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  .ico-bim--over-img {
    left: 5px;
    right: inherit;
    top: 5px;
  }
  .ico-lnb-valid--over-img {
    left: calc(100% - 47px);
    top: 5px;
  }
}
```

There, the only rule that changes is for `left` in `ico-lnb-valid--over-img`.

Most probably I'll have to add some other rules for different media queries, but start from and using some of the code already defined.

How can I refactor this?

Comment: Don't define your common rules inside of the media queries, only define what changes inside of them in your given case

Comment: I'm able to use sass if it changes something, don't know why they removed the tag.

Comment: I removed the tag because this is unrelated to SASS, this is just regular css refactoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user8424881 is correct -- only those things that differ from one media query to another need be included within the media queries.

The code can look like this:

```
/* No media queries needed */

.list__figure {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}
.list__content {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.ico-bim--over-img {
  left: 5px;
  right: inherit;
  top: 5px;
}
.ico-lnb-valid--over-img {
  top: 5px;
}

/* Media queries below */

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
   .ico-lnb-valid--over-img {
    left: 78px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1040px) {
  .ico-lnb-valid--over-img {
    left: calc(100% - 47px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the duplicates out of the media query.

```
.list__figure { 
         margin-right: 20px; 
         width: 80px; 
}

.list__content { 
          width: calc(100% - 100px); 
} 

.ico-bim--over-img {
           left: 5px; 
           right: inherit;
           top: 5px;
 } 

.ico-lnb-valid--over-img { 
           left: 78px; 
           top: 5px; 
}  

@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1040px) {

      .ico-lnb-valid--over-img {
            calc(100% - 47px);
       }
}
```

Comment: What about the `@media only screen and (max-width:768px)` media queries?

Comment: If its relevant in your case, you could creat a different  query which supports both : 
@media only screen and (max-width:1040px)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the duplicates out of the media query and leave the one for the left property in. You dont have to use media queries unless it is required for what you attempt to achieve.

Comment: Please provide the code to make your answer more complete